# Qgis 1.8 Lisboa does not have Join attributes (only Join attributes by location)

Tags: fields-attributes

I installed 1.8 Lisboa.
I tried to join to the attribute table more
data (more columns ), but
Vector/Datamanagement Tools/ 
Join attributes by location

there were also not "Join attributes" alternative.

b) I installed 1.4 and there was 
Vector/Datamanagement Tools/ Join attributes

2) what to do, when attribute table
has only Nulls, how to edit, the edit button
does not work nor 1.4 and 1.8

operation system: Windows XP
IBM ThinkPad T60

Answer (score 1):

Add the table or layer you want to join with to your table of contests. Then right click your source layer, select Properties, then in the Properties window go to the Joins tab.  Click the + button, select the layer you want to join to, and pick the join fields.

This is only available in QGIS 1.7 or greater.

Edit:  I forgot to mention, if the table you're joining to is non-spatial you still use the "Add Vector Layer" button.  Just change the filter on the file menu to "All files".